# Is this shorthand function possible in js?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, is is possible to do an inline function return, something like:

```
$.each([1,2,3], function(index, variation) {
    html_bar += '<li class="foo '+ (return (index === 1) ? 'active': '' ;)+'">bar</li>';
});
```

the above doesn't work of course, just wondering if any shorthand function exist for the:

```
$.each([1,2,3], function(index, variation) {
    var active = (index === 1) ? 'active': '' ;
    html_bar += '<li class="foo '+ active +'">bar</li>';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `return`

```
html_bar += '<li class="foo '+ (index === 1 ? 'active': '') +'">bar</li>';
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, if I get the question right, but how about

```
$.each([1,2,3], function(index, variation) {
    html_bar += '<li class="foo '+ (index === 1? 'active' : '')+'">bar</li>';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to return something from an .each callback? And who should receive the returned value?

The whole point of using this sort of constructions is to generate so-called side effects without bothering to command these operations one by one through an explicit iteration.

In your case, the side effect is to add characters to the string html_bar, which eventually is ready to become some markup in your page. Just remove the 'return' statement from your first example and you're done.